# How do I re-size my SVGs using raphael 1.5.2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have my paths using this format:

```
    Region2: {
    name: "Region2",
    slug: "Region2",
    url: "#",
    path: "M362.379,162.846l0.329-3..."
}
```

And it would be great if I could add another parameter for size, or if I could target Region2 in another line of Javascript to change the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.scale()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.scale). Is there a reason you have to use an old version of the library? It's now at 2.1.0.

Comment: Do note that scale is deprecated -- transform( ["S", scale_x, scale_y] ) would be more "correct" (though I do have mixed feelings about correctness in general)

Comment: Same here, though not sure transform was in v1.5.2

Comment: Oohhhhhhhh, that's entirely my bad -- I overlooked the version #.  Many apologies!